# Google Play - Android app not showing up after 24 hours

Tags: android, google-play

My app is not showing up in console it says the app is published but it's been 24 hour and I can't see my app on play store even with the direct link.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchemall.hd.activity

4 days ago my app got suspended because it downloads YouTube videos. But after that I modified the app and now it download videos from sites such as daily motion viemo etc Not from youtube. There are tons of apps which do this. Any one have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I just unpublished it and then re-published the app lets see what will happen.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the app was appeared for short time and then disappeared from market yesterday.

Comment: There was a change on Android app policy yesterday, maybe your app does not meet this new policy, check it out: https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: I just checked and there are 9 install of the app. but still not showing up in play store..